# Right Siding - To correct a wrong - I'm sure this is an expression but Google is failing me

Tags: expressions

I have been using an expression (which no one corrected me on) of **"Right Siding"** , with the understanding that it means "to correct a wrong" (assuming it was a convenient combination of the idea of "making right", "getting the right side up" or returning to the correct place)... but upon being questioned about it and doing some googling, it looks like I'm alone – did I some how make this expression up and use it for years!?

Comment: Was this question closed because of its wording or because asking about the meaning/existence of *right siding/to right side* is off-topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**right-side** v. trans. Chiefly dial. ... To put right, set in order. (OED)

> We bought a swing set with castors where Andre could set in it and
> walk around in the house. We put him in the seat to test it out.
> Before we knew it, he turned upside down with his feet in the air and
> his head on the floor still in the swing set crying ... After **right
> siding** him up and no injury, we all had a good laugh.
> [*Path Chosen: Life of a Lakota*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Path_Chosen/MYODAAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22right%20siding%22&pg=PA167&printsec=frontcover) (2013) p.167

> GODLINESS is emulating God. "...Pursue righteousness (**right siding**
> with God and true goodness), godliness (which is the loving fear of
> god and being Christ-like), faith, love steadfastness (patient), and
> gentleness of heart."  1 Timothy 6:11 AMP
> [*Cherish Each Moment*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Cherish_Each_Moment/-ta_DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22right%20siding%22&pg=PT37&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

> The fact is that no one can earn salvation by their own works because
> the cost is just too great. It takes a proper understanding of the
> gospel and a **right siding** with the gospel in order to fully
> comprehend this reality.
> *[Study to Show Yourself Approved](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Study_to_Show_Yourself_Approved/72QwDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22right%20siding%22&pg=PT37&printsec=frontcover)* (2017)

> Mr. REARDON. Partially, Mr. Chairman, I know North Carolina has worked
> real hard in preparedness in some areas. However the issue that you
> brought up about economic stability and **right siding** that industry
> that may be affected by that act of terrorism, I would say we are not
> prepared for. There is a lot of work that we need to do to develop
> capability and capacity.
> *[Evaluating the threat of agro-terrorism: hearing before the ...](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Evaluating_the_threat_of_agro_terrorism/CyqRvOVwiPQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22right%20siding%22&pg=PA25&printsec=frontcover)* (2005) p.25

So far, I haven't found another dictionary with an entry for *right(-)side*.

Comment: Perfect- thank you so much for saving my sanity!